# Update json in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am not a regular user of Postgresql, I have read some documentation but I am afraid to run the wrong query and I do not want to damage a database in production.

I need to edit the url field of the next json:

```
server=> select * from parameter;
     name     |                 value                  
--------------+----------------------------------------
 dataaccs_ftp | {\r                                   +
              | "url": "url.url.com", \r+
              | "username": "xxxxxxx", \r           +
              | "password": "xxxxxxx",\r           +
              | "files": ["xxx.zip", "xxx.zip"]\r +
              | }
 fldr_folders | {\r                                   +
              | "proc": "xxxxx", \r       +
              | "done": "xxxxxx", \r       +
              | "error": "xxxxxxx"\r       +
              | }
(2 rows)
```

I need to know if the following query is correct to perform the task:

```
UPDATE parameter SET dataaccs_ftp = jsonb_set(dataaccs_ftp,'{"url":"newurl.url.com"}'
```

Thanks for the help.

Regards,

Comment: What happend when you tested this query?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `jsonb_set` looks entirely wrong here.  The following should do what you need:

```sql
UPDATE parameter SET value = 
  jsonb_set(
      value,               -- existing value
      '{url}',             -- json path for update
      '"newurl.url.com"'   -- new value
  )
WHERE name = 'dataaccs_ftp'  -- which values to update
;
```

You want to update the `value` common so that is the left hand side of the assinment.  `jsonb_set` will take the current value of `value` (1st param), look for the data at `{url}` (second param, a json path) and replace with the value in the last argument.  Double quotes inside single quotes as it needs to be a json value.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e6c36c23fc8414371557af63ec25f6b3

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE json_update_test(yada jsonb) ;
INSERT INTO json_update_test (yada ) VALUES ('{"url":"newurl.url.com"}');
UPDATE json_update_test SET yada['url'] = '"example.com"';
SELECT * FROM json_update_test ;
          yada          
------------------------
 {"url": "example.com"}
(1 row)
```

notice that the example here accesses the object by reference.  Also, the double quotes inside the single quotes make the string a valid jsonb object.

From this example (and coding blind here) your update would look like:

```sql
UPDATE parameter 
SET value['url'] = '"newurl.url.com"'
WHERE "name" = 'dataaccs_ftp';
```